# Compiler error about class graph being not finitary due to a expansively recursive type parameter

Tags: scala, inheritance, compiler-construction, types, language-design

With this piece of code:

```
trait B[T]
trait C[T]
class A[T] extends B[A[C[T]]]
```

I get the following error:

```
error: class graph is not finitary because type parameter T is expansively recursive
       class A[T] extends B[A[C[T]]]
               ^
```

Can someone explain what the error message is about, why `T` is infinitely recursive and why the following code works?

```
class A[T] extends B[A[T]]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [Scala 2.9 specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (note that this is in the Change Log as a change that was introduced in 2.4, so it's not a "new restriction" in 2.9):

> The implementation of subtyping has been changed to prevent infinite
>   recursions. Termination of subtyping is now ensured by a new
>   restriction of class graphs to be finitary.

[Kennedy and Pierce](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64041) explain why infinitary class graphs are a problem:

> Even disregarding subtyping, infinite closure presents a problem for
>   language implementers, as they must take care not to create type
>   representations for supertypes in an eager fashion, else non-
>   termination is the result. For example, the .NET Common Language
>   Runtime supports generic instantiation and generic inheritance in
>   its intermediate language targeted by C. The class loader maintains a
>   hash table of types currently loaded, and when loading a new type it
>   will attempt to load its supertypes, add these to the table, and in
>   turn load the type arguments involved in the supertype.

Fortunately, as Kennedy and Pierce point out, there's a convenient way to check whether a class graph is infinitary. I'm using their definitions throughout this answer.

First I'll make your type variables distinct for clarity:

```
trait B[X]
trait C[Y]
class A[Z] extends B[A[C[Z]]]
```

Next we construct the type parameter dependency graph using Kennedy and Pierce's definition. The only declaration that's going to add edges to the graph is the last one, for `A`. They give the following rules for building the graph:

> For each declaration `C <X̄> <:: T` and each subterm `D<T̄>` of `T`, if `T_j = X_i` add a *non-expansive* edge `C#i → D#j`; if `X_i` is a proper subterm of `T_j` add an *expansive* edge`C#i → D#j`

So first we look at `Z` and `C[Z]`, which gives us a non-expansive edge from `Z` to `Y`. Next `Z` and `A[C[Z]]` gives us an expansive edge from `Z` to `Z`, and `Z` and `B[A[C[Z]]]` gives us an expansive edge from `Z` to `X`:

[image: Graph for the bad version]

I've indicated non-expansive edges with dashed arrows and expansive edges with solid ones. We have a cycle with an expansive edge, which is a problem:

> Infinitary class tables are characterized precisely by those graphs
>   that contain a cycle with at least one expansive edge.

This doesn't happen for `class A[Z] extends B[A[Z]]`, which has the following graph:

[image: Graph for the good version]

See the paper for a proof that a class table is infinitary iff it's expansive.

---

Comment: I wish I could give an addition +1 just for the graphics. Very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is really well formed, but also quite complex. As this page is very high on google search results for 'non finitary graph', I thought I'd add a 'hand waving' explanation. The class definitions in your problem give us this subtype relation element:

```
A[X] <: B[A[C[X]]]
```

The compiler sees however that the definition is recursive (uses A[_] in the definition of A[X]) and tries to expand it, so it substitutes the argument type `C[Z]` for the parameter type `X` in the definition of `A` and obtains:

```
A[C[X]] <: B[B[A[C[X]]]
```

And we see where it is going: definition of `A` can be expanded indefinitely.
Note there is no subtype relation with `A[X]`, as the type is invariant in `X`.

I know nothing about compilers and the maths behind the problem, I simply tried to come to some conclusion from my observations as to 'what' happens, without an answer to 'why'. What I said is thus most likely factually incorrect or inprecise, but the take out is:

*if you use a type constructor `A` in the definition of `A`
(which can be done only as a type argument to another type (`B`)),
you cannot give it as a type argument a complex term (`C[X]`)*.

The fact that `X` occurs inside the `C[X]` argument is irrelevant:

```
type Z
type A[X] <: B[A[C[Z]]]
```

leads us to:

```
A[C[Z]] <: B[B[A[C[Z]]]
```

This doesn't happen if you use simply `A[X]` in the definition of `A[X]`, because `X` itself is not expanded.

To be more constructive, one can try to work around it by giving `B` as arguments type constructor `A` and the argument `C[X]`:

```
trait A[X] extends B[A, C[X]]
```

And apply `A` to `C[X]` in the body of `B` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is really well formed, but also quite complex. As this page is very high on google search results for 'non finitary graph', I thought I'd add a 'hand waving' explanation. The class definitions in your problem give us this subtype relation element:

```
A[X] <: B[A[C[X]]]
```

The compiler sees however that the definition is recursive (uses A[_] in the definition of A[X]) and tries to expand it, so it substitutes the argument type `C[Z]` for the parameter type `X` in the definition of `A` and obtains:

```
A[C[X]] <: B[B[A[C[X]]]
```

And we see where it is going: definition of `A` can be expanded indefinitely.
Note there is no subtype relation with `A[X]`, as the type is invariant in `X`.

I know nothing about compilers and the maths behind the problem, I simply tried to come to some conclusion from my observations as to 'what' happens, without an answer to 'why'. What I said is thus most likely factually incorrect or inprecise, but the take out is:

*if you use a type constructor `A` in the definition of `A`
(which can be done only as a type argument to another type (`B`)),
you cannot give it as a type argument a complex term (`C[X]`)*.

The fact that `X` occurs inside the `C[X]` argument is irrelevant:

```
type Z
type A[X] <: B[A[C[Z]]]
```

leads us to:

```
A[C[Z]] <: B[B[A[C[Z]]]
```

This doesn't happen if you use simply `A[X]` in the definition of `A[X]`, because `X` itself is not expanded.

Also: if the compiler throws a `StackOverflowError` in the typer phase, this may be one of the causes:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type$$anon$1.apply(Types.scala:794)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$SingleType.mapOver(Types.scala:1477)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type$$anon$1.apply(Types.scala:794)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$SingleType.mapOver(Types.scala:1477)
```

Stack trace added in case someone encounters the problem and tries to search for it.